# Update Cursor for NULLS and Blanks

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am using the following update cursor, but when I execute it, it does not error, but also makes no changes. I am trying to Update a field where any NULL, Blank, and NEW values will be updated with 'New'.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("contacts", 'Contact_Status1') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if  row[0] is None or ' ' or 'NEW'  :
            row[0]= "New"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the entire `if` test for each `or`, so instead of

```
if  row[0] is None or ' ' or 'NEW':
```

you need to put `row[0] ==` with the `or`.

```
if  row[0] is None or row[0] == ' ' or row[0] =='NEW':
```

So in full it will look like

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("contacts", 'Contact_Status1') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if  row[0] is None or row[0] == ' ' or row[0] =='NEW':
            row[0]= "New"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: So I was missing the if , and should of used == instead? Why the == for Blanks and Null values? Because they are not a real value?

Comment: @winscott68 Not exactly.  You were missing the `row[0] ==` for the subsequent tests.  You can't just specify `if myvalue = 1 or 2 or 3`, you have to specify `if myvalue = 1 or myvalue = 2 or myvalue = 3`.  In Python, an equals test requires a double `=`, so it would be `if myvalue == 1 or myvalue == 2 or myvalue == 3`.  The `Null` (or `None` in Python) requires the `is` keyword rather than `==`.

Comment: Ok so strings will get == and NULL requires is

Comment: @winscott68 Yes